# Do the Taylor series of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ depend on the identity $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x =1$?

Tags: combinatorics, trigonometry, power-series, taylor-expansion

I had this crazy idea trying to prove the Pythagorean trigonometric identity;$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$$by squaring the infinite Taylor series of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. But it came out quite beautiful, involving also a combinatorics identitie.

The proof:

$$\sin x=\frac{x}{1}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\\\\sin^2x=x^2-x^4\left (\frac{1}{1!3!}+\frac{1}{3!1!}\right )+x^6\left (\frac{1}{1!5!}+\frac{1}{3!3!}+\frac{1}{5!1!}\right )-...\\\\\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\\\\cos^2x\!=\!1\!-\!x^2\left(\!\frac{1}{0!2!}\!+\!\frac{1}{2!0!}\!\right)\!+\!x^4\left(\!\frac{1}{0!4!}\!+\!\frac{1}{2!2!}\!+\!\frac{1}{4!0!}\!\right)\!-\!x^6\left(\!\frac{1}{0!6!}\!+\!\frac{1}{2!4!}\!+\!\frac{1}{4!2!}\!+\!\frac{1}{6!0!}\!\right)\!+...$$We should have shown that the series for both $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ converge absolutely (since we changed the arrangement), but it's obvious since the absolute value of all terms of $\sin x+\cos x$ add up to $e^x$.$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=\\=1-x^2\left(\frac{1}{0!2!}-\frac{1}{1!1!}+\frac{1}{2!0!}\right)+x^4\left(\frac{1}{0!4!}-\frac{1}{1!3!}+\frac{1}{2!2!}-\frac{1}{3!1!}+\frac{1}{4!0!}\right)-x^6\left(\frac{1}{0!6!}-\frac{1}{1!5!}+\frac{1}{2!4!}-\frac{1}{3!3!}+\frac{1}{4!2!}-\frac{1}{5!1!}+\frac{1}{6!0!}\right)+...=\\\\=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^k\binom{2n}{k}}{(2n)!}$$
Since we can show easily that $\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}=0$ by expanding $(1-1)^n$ using Binom's formula. So:$$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1-0+0-0+...=1$$

I think it's beautiful. I just wanted to ask, do Taylor's series of those functions depend on this identity? Because if they do, the proof will be circular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice proof! To address your question,

> Do Taylor's series of those functions depend on this identity? Because if they do, the proof will be circular.

You are right to be worried about circularity! However, which concepts or theorems *depend* on which others is a matter of certain flexibility. Often, we take one thing to be the definition of a concept, and then have to prove the other properties as theorems -- but we could alternately have used some other property as a definition, and then the original definition would have to be a theorem.

Specific to your case, I have seen definitions of $\sin$ and $\cos$ where we start by defining $\sin$ using arclength, then we *define* $\cos x$ to satisfy $\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1$. If we take this approach, certainly, there is nothing to prove. However, this is not the only possible approach! It is also common to define $\sin$ and $\cos$ using their Taylor series. Under this approach, you have given a very nice proof that $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$.
Your proof could also be valid if we define $\sin$ and $\cos$ to be a basis of functions satisfying $f''(x) = -f(x)$.

In summary, it depends on what you define $\sin$ and $\cos$ to be; however, your proof is not necessarily circular. And it is a nice example of deriving a result about some functions from their Taylor series.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but what about the usual definition of $sin$ and $cos$, as the proportion of sides of a triangle, that of course also doesn't depend on $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$, am I right?

Comment: @76david76: Are $\sin$ and $\cos$ usually *defined* that way?  That's often the way they're introduced, but then what is $\sin 3\pi/2$?

Comment: It can be an expansion of the first definition. Is there really no way to define these functions out of the unit circle?

Comment: @76david76 Most functions in analysis are not defined using geometry because we would first need a rigorous definition of points, lines, and so on. It is much easier to define them using taylor series. However, yes, you can develop these functions using the unit circle. When I said "we start by defining sinsin using arclength", that is referring to how we let $\sin \theta$ be the $y$-coordinate of the point on the unit circle such that the arc length from $(1,0)$ is $2 \pi y$. If you define them using the unit circle, $\cos^2 \theta + \sin62 \theta$ is immediate like I said.

Answer (score 2):

No, they do not depend on the Pythagoren identity. Using the differential equations that define $\sin$ and $\cos$

- $\cos(0) = 1$
- $\sin(0) = 0$
- $\cos' = -\sin$
- $\sin' = \cos$

it's very easy to show that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\cos(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^ix^{2i}}{(2x)!}$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\sin(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^ix^{2i + 1}}{(2x + 1)!}$.

Answer (score 1):

You are just showing that the Pythagorean theorem is a consequence of some property of the (complex) exponential function, there is no circularity in such argument. For instance, we may define, for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$,
$$ f(z)=e^{z}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^n}{n!} \tag{1}$$
and prove through a combinatorial argument that such a function fulfills $e^{z}\cdot e^{w}=e^{z+w}$.
Since the Taylor coefficients at $0$ of such analytic function are real, we have $f(\bar{z})=\overline{f(z)}$,
 hence for any $\rho\in\mathbb{R}$
$$ \left\| e^{i\rho}\right\| = e^{i\rho}\cdot e^{-i\rho} = e^0 = 1. \tag{2}$$
If we define $\cos(\rho)$ and $\sin(\rho)$ as the real/imaginary part of $e^{i\rho}$, we get that
$$ \sin(\rho)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n \rho^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!},\qquad \cos(\rho)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n \rho^{2n}}{(2n)!}\tag{3} $$
and $(2)$ can be read as:
$$ \sin^2(\rho)+\cos^2(\rho) = 1.\tag{4}$$

Comment: I was going to upvote this answer except I saw a problem so I downvoted it. It is true that $\forall \rho \in \mathbb{R}\sin^2(\rho) + \cos^2(\rho) = 1$. However, you didn't prove that and that's the reason I downvoted your answer. Without the extra detail of the Pythagorean identity, I would have considered your answer good and upvoted it. It shows that there is a very nice easy way to prove what the Taylor series' of $\sin$ and $\cos$ are that's actually much easier than squaring the Taylor series of $\sin$ then subtracting it from 1 then figuring out which square root of it is $\cos$.

Comment: @Timothy: the Pithagorean theorem is proved in (2).